# what does read-only data section consist?

Tags: c

In C language programming, which content of variable will store in
read-only data section?

```
void func( int i ){
    printf("%d\n", i);
}

int main()
{
    const str = "const string";
    int b;

    func(b);
    return 0;
}
```

Look at the program before, what, I already know, will be stored in
read-only data section

- `constant string` like "const str = "const string""
- `jump table(switch ... case)`
- `printf/scanf fomat string` like "%d\n".

What do I miss? And for a ordinary application, what's the size of
read-only data section?
Is there any difference between GCC with LLVM about the content of
read-only data section?

Comment: you lack initialization for your `b` you are passing garbage to `func`

Comment: None. Because the C **language** does not have an idea about such a section. This is an implementation detail. `const` in C is just a promise of the programmer not to change a variable after initialisation, otherwise undefined behaviour is invoked. And whether a `switch` statement results in a table depends on many factors, let alone that it may also be placed in code space (e.g. ARM). If you are intereseted in that, you should read about compiler construction and code generation/optimisation.

Comment: I bet that there are C compilers for architectures that don't even have read only data sections.

Comment: Memory allocation scheme (data segment, code segment, stack, heap) is not defined by the C language standard. It is compiler-implementation dependent.

Comment: I list this C program to just show which variable will store into read-only section! I know that C language does not have an idea about sections , which is the details of C compiler. I want to know this detail implemented in C compiler.